# How do I easily separate multiple objects on an artboard to new SVG files w/ sizes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I'm new to Adobe Illustrator, so please forgive me if this seems like a dumb question.  I have an SVG file with the USA map and all 50 states.  I need to create 50 individual SVGs, one for each state.  I was able to complete this by selecting each state and then exporting my selection.

However, the SVG selection export does not allow me to define an image size.  I'm assuming this is because SVGs are scaleable?..  I would like to be able to define the default width of these states in my SVG export.

How do I assign dimensions of the states in these SVG exports?

SVG states file:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zhawu1lle2rm00/State%20Outline.svg?dl=0

Comment: About saving the SVG [size](https://watb.co.uk/blog/how-to-make-sure-your-svgs-have-height-and-width-attributes-using-illustrator-cc)

Comment: Please make an [edit] to include the SVG code in your question as this may be flagged as spam.